# get all "NA" for p-value when using tryCatch for t.test in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data with treatment vs. control, each of the in 3 replicates. Column 1 to 3 in the data is treatment and column 4 to 6 is control., respectively.

I performed t.test in R like the following:

```
df$p.value <- apply (df, 1, function(x) t.test(x[1:3], x[4:6],alternative = "two.sided", paired = TRUE)$p.value)
```

When I perform t.test on my data. I received error:

```
Error in t.test.default(x[1:3], x[4:6], alternative = "two.sided", paired = TRUE) :data are essentially constant
```

Therefore, I wish to turn the error into "NA" when there is error for certain rows by using `tryCatch` as below:

```
df$p.value <- tryCatch({
  apply(df, 1, function(x) t.test(x[1:3], x[4:6],alternative = "two.sided", paired = TRUE)$p.value)
}, error = function(e) {NA})
```

However, it returns all "NA" despite I have some comparable data. How could I fix this script?

Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
apply (df, 1, 
   function(x) tryCatch({
     t.test(x[1:3], x[4:6],alternative = "two.sided", paired = TRUE)$p.value
   }, error = function(e) {NA}))
```